# change value of a key in array and rearrange whole multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

i have an array below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => task 1
            [tech_user_id] => 1
            [dev_priority] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => task 2
            [tech_user_id] => 1
            [dev_priority] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => task 3
            [tech_user_id] => 1
            [dev_priority] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => task 4
            [tech_user_id] => 1
            [dev_priority] => 4
        )

)
```

I want to change the priority of a task and rearrange the whole array.

Eg: if i want to change the `dev_priority` of task `title = "task 3"` from 3 to 1, then `dev_priority` of "task 1" should be 2 and `dev_priority` for "task 2" should be 3.

want to write a function rearrange where we pass `$id` and `$set_priority` and `$set_priority` should assigned against the given `$id` and whole array rearrange based on `dev_priority`.

```
rearrange($id, $set_priority) {
    // ...
}
```

Expected Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => task 3
            [tech_user_id] => 1
            [dev_priority] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => task 1
            [tech_user_id] => 1
            [dev_priority] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => task 2
            [tech_user_id] => 1
            [dev_priority] => 3
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => task 4
            [tech_user_id] => 1
            [dev_priority] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: Sounds fair enough. What efforts have you made so far?

Comment: Just get rid of `dev_priority` and use the intrinsic order of the items in the array…? Or, if you need the `dev_priority` property to mirror that: move the actual item in the array, and then iterate over the array once to set `dev_priority` to the value of index…

Comment: Does the reassignment have any order?

Comment: Why dont't you assign the new priority and then sort the array based on the priority. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/how-to-sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: @vivek_23 yes in ascending order.

Comment: @codex Ok. You said `Eg: if i want to change the dev_priority of task title = "task 3" from 3 to 1, then dev_priority of "task 1" should be 2 and dev_priority for "task 2" should be 3.`. So, do you assign this, or you want it to get assigned automatically?

Comment: @vivek_23 As i said, want to create a function where id and dev_priority will pass and this priority assigned to given id and rest of the tasks "dev_priority" would be automatically reassigned and arrange in ascending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

function reArrange(&$result,$id,$new_dev_priority){
    $curr_index  = array_search($id,array_column($result,"id"),true);
    $limit_index = array_search($new_dev_priority,array_column($result,"dev_priority"),true);

    $process_node = $result[$curr_index];
    $curr_dev_priority = $process_node['dev_priority'];
    if($curr_dev_priority === $new_dev_priority) return; // return if same priority was assigned.    
    $offset = $curr_dev_priority > $new_dev_priority ? -1 : 1;

    /* rearrange by relocating elements to a new location(this is a minimized shift) */
    while($curr_index != $limit_index){
        $result[$curr_index] = $result[$curr_index + $offset];
        $result[$curr_index]['dev_priority'] = $result[$curr_index]['dev_priority'] - $offset;        
        $curr_index += $offset;
    }  

    $process_node['dev_priority'] = $new_dev_priority; // assign new dev priority
    $result[$curr_index] = $process_node;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/nggja

- We get the current index of the process and the index of the process which has our desired new dev priority.
- We do this because we only want to shift elements from our current location **till** our desired location. Shifting irrelevant processes out of this range is trivial.
- We define a variable called `offset` which just determines the direction of shift. `-1` for up and `1` for down.
- Time complexity: **O(n)** (in worst case), Space Complexity: **O(1)**.

Comment: i stuck in few cases but Thanxs buddy, this is working